# I am attempting to create a BST and getting the same error: 'build_bst': redefinition, different basic types

Tags: c

```
/* Here is my structure */
typedef struct Node {
    char word[11];
    char description[101];
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* left;
} Node;

int main (void) {
    /* I call my function first here using this format */
    Node *root = NULL;
    build_bst(&root);
}

/* This is the actual start of the called function */
void build_bst(struct Node** root) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Is the argument when I call the function in the wrong format? The error I get on visual studio is

> 'build_bst': redefinition; different basic types.

Comment: Is that literally how you are trying to call it?

Comment: yes,  is the parameter that I am giving it the wrong format?

Comment: it is in my main, but to save space I didnt include all of my main function

Comment: Side note: `void build_bst(struct Node** root)` can be turned into `void build_bst(Node** root)`, that is one of the main reasons you use typedef in this context.

Comment: If you don't have a prototype for `build_bst` before you call it, the compiler will assume it returns `int` in the old C rules. If you enable enforcement of new C rules on your compiler, it should not allow you to call `build_bst` without a prototype in scope.

Comment: But in any case, if you create a proper prototype for `build_bst` above main, you should be ok. `void build_bst(Node **);` would be a sufficient prototype.